# Is there anyway to allow only Jenkins to do push in bit bucket?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

In my bit bucket nobody can push directly on the branch `pre-release`, they need to do a `pull request`.

So what I am trying to do now is to build a `pipeline` in `jenkins` to increase the versions in the `pom.xml` of my branch `pre-release` but it fails when it tries to directly `push` into the branch.

I am wondering if there's anyway to allow only `jenkins` to `push` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you set branch permissions (repository -> settings -> branch permissions) "Prevent changes without a pull request". There you should be able to exclude a user or group:

[image]

Comment: Oh perfect!! that's exactly what i was looking for! Thank you! :)